# React -- Using functions from the ContextAPI in the useEffect hooks has missing dependencies warning

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint, react-context

I am using the react Context to store some global states and functions. However, when I use a function defined in the context inside a useEffect hook, it causes a warning: "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: mapContext".

The code example is like this:

```
const mapContext= useContext(MapContext);

useEffect(()=>{
 mapContext.getAPIToken();
 mapContext.getAPICredit();
}, [])
```

If I add `mapContext` to the dependencies array, it will cause an infinite loop since the `getAPIToken` and `getAPICredit` function will update the state of `mapContext`.

I know the warning can be suppressed by using the `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` comment, however, I was wondering if there another way to truly solve this warning?

EDIT:
Implementation of getAPICredit() looks like this:

```
const getAPICredit = async () => {
    try {
      const results = await axios.get('/get_apicredit', {
        headers: { Authorization: authState.accessToken },
      });
      dispatch({
        type: GET_APICREDIT,
        payload: results.data,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      handleError(err.response);
    }
  };
```

EDIT2

code snippet of the `mapContext`:

```
 const initialState = {
    userAPI: { key: '', credit: 0 },
  };
 const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(MapReducer, initialState);
 return (
    <MapContext.Provider
      value={{
        userAPI: state.userAPI,
        getAPIToken,
        getAPICredit,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </MapContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default MapState;
```

the `mapReducer` snippet:

```
case GET_APICREDIT: {
      return {
        ...state,
        userAPI: {
          ...state.userAPI,
          credit: action.payload,
        },
      };
    }
```

Comment: Either disable the eslint rule, as you stated correctly or do not copy/recreate the mapContext object, only mutate.

Comment: Can you add the implementation of `mapContext`?

Comment: pass the functions, not the object `const { getAPIToken } = mapContext`

Comment: he is right, @azium, might work as well `[mapContext.getAPIToken, mapContext. getAPICredit]`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. @azium, @Julian Kleine, I tried both methods before, however neither works. For the @azium method, the dependencies array needs ```getAPIToken```, and if I added to the array, it causes an infinite loop. For the @Julian Kleine method, it still requires ```mapContext``` in the depencies array

Comment: @Leon it shouldn't cause an infinite loop to add a function,  something else is wrong with your code then. can you post the context?

Comment: @azium, thank you for the reply. I attached the code snippet of the context and reducer. The reason it causes infinte loop is because the ```getAPICredit()``` and ```getAPIToken``` functions update the state of ```mapContext```. Therefore, if ```mapContext``` is included in the depencies array, the ```useEffect``` hooks will update the state of ```mapContext``` and causes re-render again